# Pause and seek in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a `SeekBar` and a `MediaPlayer`. I want to seek while it's paused, but is seems that docs lies to me:

> Please note that seekTo(int) can also be called in the other states,
>   such as Prepared, Paused and PlaybackCompleted state.

As usual, on Android I have to write workarounds instead of code (and in which state is `MediaPlayer` at this time I can't know, so this table and state machine is completely useless). Because instead of `onSeekComplete` `onCompletion` (over 9000 times, I'm not joking) method is called! `onSeekComplete` is called only after calling `seekTo` from `onPrepared` (WHY, GOD, WHY???). I don't even know what to do. I spent about 5 hours on it and nothing is fixed. What can I do?

## UPD

Here is my code.

```java
private void setupMediaPlayer() {
    savedMediaPlayerState = null;

    mediaPlayer = application.getMediaPlayer();

    String mp3Path = "/path/to/mp3";

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Path);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(android.widget.SeekBar sb, int i, boolean b) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Progress changed! %d", i));
    if (b) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        updateProgressBarAndDurationLabels(i, mediaPlayer.getDuration(), false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(android.widget.SeekBar sb) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(android.widget.SeekBar sb) {
    int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = sb.getProgress();// * totalDuration / 100;

    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    updateProgressBar();

    isSeeking = false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if (!isSeeking) {
        Log.i(TAG, "completed"); // Called over 9000 times
        audioStopped();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i2) {
    return false;    // Error -38 lol
}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("seek to: %d", mp.getCurrentPosition()));
    isSeeking = false;
}
```

Comment: Let's see some code. I've used `seekTo()` on several occasions.

Comment: @Geobits I'd added some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After adding the `onErrorListener`, I discovered that the error with `what=-38` is happening here. However, returning `true` from `onError` solved my problem. Nobody knows what does it mean.